# How to reset items in legend area in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have met a weird requirement for `Highcharts`:

In Highcharts we can choose to show the legend or not,the items value is coming from the data.But now I need to remove the duplicate item if they have the same color and reset the value to a new one.

As the image shows below: *Task C* and `Task E` have the same color,so we only need to preserve one item and rename it.

I have checked on the official website at **[highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/)**,but still do not find an effective way,I have attached my test code below,can anyone help me,please?

Thanks in advance!

Description image:

[image]

Test code:

```js
   function formatDate(val){
      var d = new Date(val);
      var cd = d.getDate();
      var cm = d.getMonth() + 1;
      var cy = d.getFullYear();
   return cy + "-" + cm + "-" + cd;
   }

   $(function () {
     
 $('#container').highcharts({
 
     chart: {
         type: 'columnrange',
         inverted: true
     },
     
     title: {
         text: 'Equipments Usage'
     },
     
  subtitle: {
         text: 'Display based on date'
     },
 
     xAxis: {
         categories: ['Equipment A', 'Equipment B', 'Equipment C', 'Equipment D', 'Equipment E', 'Equipment F'],
      gridLineDashStyle: 'longdash',
   gridLineWidth: 1,
     },
     
     yAxis: {
         title: {
             text: 'Equipment use time range'
         },
   type:'datetime',
   labels: {
    formatter:function(){
       return formatDate(this.value);
    }
   },
     },

     plotOptions: {
         columnrange: {
          dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           formatter: function () {
        if(this.y == this.point.low){
            return "";
        }
        if(this.series.options.finished){
            return "<span style='color:green'>\u25CF</span> ";
        }
           }
          }
         }
     },

     tooltip: {
         formatter:function(){
               return this.series.name + '<br/>'
             + 'Start: <b>' + formatDate(this.point.low) + '</b><br/>'
             + 'End: <b>' + formatDate(this.point.high) + '</b><br/>'
       + 'Percent: <b>' + this.series.options.percent + '</b>';
            }
     },
     
     legend: {
         enabled: true,
   borderWidth:1,
   labelFormatter:function(){
      return this.name;
   }
     },
 
     series: [
    {
         name: 'Task A',
   percent:'20%',
   finished:true,
   color:'lightgray',
         data: [
                [1, Date.UTC(2018, 2, 6, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 2, 16, 10)],
    [3, Date.UTC(2018, 2, 9, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 2, 26, 10)],
   ],
       },
    {
         name: 'TaskB',
   percent:'40%',
   finished:false,
   color:'lightblue',
         data: [
                [1, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 6, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 4, 16, 10)],
    [2, Date.UTC(2018, 4, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 5, 10, 10)],
    [3, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 8, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 4, 5, 10)]
   ],
       },
    {
         name: 'Task C',
   percent:'60%',
   finished:false,
   color:'#b2f442',
         data: [
       [0, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 4, 6, 10)],
       [1, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 16, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 3, 26, 10)],
                [4, Date.UTC(2018, 4, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 5, 6, 10)],
   ],
       },
    {
         name: 'Task D',
   percent:'60%',
   finished:false,
   color:'red',
         data: [
       [0, Date.UTC(2018, 5, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 6, 10)],
       [1, Date.UTC(2018, 5, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 16, 10)]
   ],
       },
    {
         name: 'Task E',
   percent:'55%',
   finished:false,
   color:'#b2ff42',
         data: [
       [2, Date.UTC(2018, 6, 1, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 16, 10)],
       [4, Date.UTC(2018, 6, 1, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 10, 10)]
   ],
       }
  
  ]
 
 });
    
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   
      <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Test code run result
[image]

Answer (score 2):

check [plotOptions.series.linkedTo](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo) and change the series name accordingly

> linkedTo: string
>   The id of another series to link to. Additionally, the value can be ":previous" to link to the previous series. When two series are linked, only the first one appears in the legend. Toggling the visibility of this also toggles the linked series.
>   Defaults to undefined.

```js
function formatDate(val) {
  var d = new Date(val);
  var cd = d.getDate();
  var cm = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var cy = d.getFullYear();
  return cy + "-" + cm + "-" + cd;
}

$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange',
      inverted: true
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Equipments Usage'
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: 'Display based on date'
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Equipment A', 'Equipment B', 'Equipment C', 'Equipment D', 'Equipment E', 'Equipment F'],
      gridLineDashStyle: 'longdash',
      gridLineWidth: 1,
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Equipment use time range'
      },
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return formatDate(this.value);
        }
      },
    },

    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function() {
            if (this.y == this.point.low) {
              return "";
            }
            if (this.series.options.finished) {
              return "<span style='color:green'>\u25CF</span> ";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.series.name + '<br/>' +
          'Start: <b>' + formatDate(this.point.low) + '</b><br/>' +
          'End: <b>' + formatDate(this.point.high) + '</b><br/>' +
          'Percent: <b>' + this.series.options.percent + '</b>';
      }
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      borderWidth: 1,
      labelFormatter: function() {
        return this.name;
      }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Task A',
        percent: '20%',
        finished: true,
        color: 'lightgray',
        data: [
          [1, Date.UTC(2018, 2, 6, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 2, 16, 10)],
          [3, Date.UTC(2018, 2, 9, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 2, 26, 10)],
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'TaskB',
        percent: '40%',
        finished: false,
        color: 'lightblue',
        data: [
          [1, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 6, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 4, 16, 10)],
          [2, Date.UTC(2018, 4, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 5, 10, 10)],
          [3, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 8, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 4, 5, 10)]
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Task C',
        id: 'taskc',
        percent: '60%',
        finished: false,
        color: '#b2f442',
        data: [
          [0, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 4, 6, 10)],
          [1, Date.UTC(2018, 3, 16, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 3, 26, 10)],
          [4, Date.UTC(2018, 4, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 5, 6, 10)],
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Task D',
        percent: '60%',
        finished: false,
        color: 'red',
        data: [
          [0, Date.UTC(2018, 5, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 6, 10)],
          [1, Date.UTC(2018, 5, 26, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 16, 10)]
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Task E',
        percent: '55%',
        finished: false,
        linkedTo: 'taskc',
        color: '#b2ff42',
        data: [
          [2, Date.UTC(2018, 6, 1, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 16, 10)],
          [4, Date.UTC(2018, 6, 1, 10), Date.UTC(2018, 6, 10, 10)]
        ],
      }

    ]

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve expected effect, you need to do an iteration over all series on `chart.events.load`, and check if some pair of series has the same color. If yes, then just update the name of first series, and set second series `linkedTo` parameter equal to name you set on first one. Please take a look at code below:

```
   chart: {
     type: 'columnrange',
     inverted: true,
     events: {
       load() {
         var chart = this,
           series = chart.series,
           mergedCount = 1;
         series.forEach(series1 => {
           series.forEach(series2 => {
             if (
               series1.options.color === series2.options.color &&
               series1 !== series2 &&
               !series1.options.linkedTo &&
               !series2.options.linkedTo
             ) {
               series1.update({
                 name: 'Merged series ' + mergedCount
               })
               series2.update({
                 linkedTo: 'Merged series ' + mergedCount
               })
             }
           })
         })
       }
     }
   }
```

Now, you've only make sure that series you want to 'merge' has the same color.

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/o83j7bkc/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo